# Как правильно вставить ListView в Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Если наследоваться от android.app.ListFragment то приложение крашится при запуске, как правильно внедрить ListView в Fragment?
Код фрагмента:

```
public class Fragment_AAC extends android.app.ListFragment {



    String[] base_AAC = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.base_AAC);

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Fragment_AAC() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static Fragment_AAC newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment_AAC fragment = new Fragment_AAC();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, base_AAC);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Разметка:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shark.sportplus.fragments.Fragment_AAC"
    android:id="@+id/nav_aac">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_aac"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Логи:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sharkitt.sportplus/com.sharkitt.sportplus.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Fragment_AAC{9fe2943} not attached to Activity
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5555)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Fragment_AAC{9fe2943} not attached to Activity
at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:805)
at com.sharkitt.sportplus.fragments.Fragment_AAC.<init>(Fragment_AAC.java:22)
at com.sharkitt.sportplus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
... 9 more
```

P.S. Наследоваться от android.support.v4.app.ListFragment не предлагать, так как FragmentTransaction перестанет работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому пригодится. Удалить следующее:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, base_AAC);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Добавить:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__aac, container, false);

        String[] base_AAC = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.base_AAC);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                base_AAC
        );

        ListView listView_aac = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_aac);
        listView_aac.setAdapter(adapter);


        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Отнаследуйтесь от обычного фрагмента и вставьте список.

Comment: В таком случае строчка setListAdapter(adapter); не будет работать

Comment: В этом случае получите список по id и установите адаптер setAdapter

Comment: список это array-string

Comment: Так адаптер то тот же использовать можно